# Jquery mobile changing text for data-add-back-btn="true" from javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm working in Jquery Mobile, and I've got a page which has a back button with this attribute:

```
data-add-back-btn="true"
```

I need to be able to change the text of it dynamically through either jquery or javascript. I've googled it quite a bit but not much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Rajaj/)**

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page2", function(){
    $("a[data-rel=back] .ui-btn-text").html('my text');

});
```

In jQM markup added for the back button, you select a span with class ui-btn-text that is the child of an A tag with data-rel=back, and then change its html.